# Error 400: invalid_request - Custom URI scheme is not supported on Chrome apps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I'm trying to run Oauth in my Chrome extension, but when I try to login, here's the error I get.

[image]

Here is what I've verified, the id of my extension, and the id of my OAuth 2.0 Client IDs is the same.

Here's my function, that runs:

```
    const signInWithGoogle = () => {
        // chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: 'google_sign_in' });
        console.log('test');
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            } else {
                console.log(token);
            }
        });
    };
```

And here is my manifest:

```
    "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "xxx",
        "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "downloads",
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus",
        "identity"
    ],
```

There's a Github issue on the same problem as well.
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/7434

Even if this doesn't work, I'd love if someone can point to an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [OAuth 2.0: authenticate users with Google](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/integrate/oauth) tutorial, you will be able to make it work, but, you must configure some extra steps on your extension.

1. **You have to add a scope in the manifest file.**

```json
{
  // ...
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "<your_extension_id>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"] // <-- here
  },
  "key": "<your_public_key>"
}
```

2. **You have to use Google Chrome browser. It doesn't work on Brave or Chromium** as you will see:

2.1 On Brave browser it didn't work because there is a bad request (I guess when Brave calls the Google API, it sends some headers into the request which Google API verifies, like user agent, it will only accept Google Chrome)

[image]

2.2 On Google Chrome it worked
[image]